# Swift: typaliasing with a protocol?

Tags: ios, swift, swift-protocols, type-alias, associated-types

I'm struggling trying to modelize something that seems basic to me.

Let's consider a fictive service/multicast delegate implementation :

```
protocol Service { }

protocol Delegate { }

protocol Service1Delegate: Delegate {
    func doSomething()
}

protocol Service1: Service {

    func foo()

    var delegates: [Service1Delegate] { get }
    func register(delegate: Service1Delegate)

}

class MyService1: Service1 {

    func foo() {
        delegates.forEach { $0.doSomething() }
    }

    private(set) var delegates = [Service1Delegate]()

    func register(delegate: Service1Delegate) {
        self.delegates.append(delegate)
    }

}

class A: Service1Delegate {

    func doSomething() {
        print("Hello A")
    }

}

class B: Service1Delegate {

    func doSomething() {
        print("Hello B")
    }

}

let service1 = MyService1()
service1.register(delegate: A())
service1.register(delegate: B())
service1.foo()
```

No problem, I get `Hello A` and `Hello B` printed.

Now consider a second service

```
protocol Service2Delegate: Delegate {
    func doSomethingElse()
}

protocol Service2: Service {

    func bar()

    var delegates: [Service2Delegate] { get }
    func register(delegate: Service2Delegate)

}

class MyService2: Service2 {

    func bar() {
        delegates.forEach { $0.doSomethingElse() }
    }

    private(set) var delegates = [Service2Delegate]()

    func register(delegate: Service2Delegate) {
        self.delegates.append(delegate)
    }

}
```

`Service1` and `Service2` both have some code in common relative to delegates that I wish to be made generic.

So I'm introducing a new protocol `Delegable` like so:

```
protocol Delegable {

    associatedtype D: Delegate

    var delegates: [D] { get}
    func register(delegate: D)

}

typealias DelegableService = Service & Delegable
```

and I'd define services like this now

```
protocol Service1: DelegableService {

    func foo()

}

protocol Service2: DelegableService {

    func bar()

}
```

However when implementing them and specifying their delegate type with a typealias, the compiler complains that my implementation do not conform to Delegable

```
class MyService1: Service1 {

    typealias D = Service1Delegate // <- the compiler does not like this, because it's not a concrete type

    func foo() {
        print("foo")
    }

    private(set) var delegates = [Service1Delegate]()

    func register(delegate: Service1Delegate) {
        self.delegates.append(delegate)
    }

}
```

It seems we can only typealias with a concrete type, not a protocol. But the concrete types are unknown for now, and will be of different nature (class A and class B), but they all conform to Service1Delegate.

Is there a solution any way to do that in Swift ?

Comment: I think that's the point of associated types.  A protocol can use an associated type to stay generic and then any concrete type that conforms to that protocol can then define its own type alias to be used in the generic functions.  Perhaps Type Constraints is what you are looking for?   Not sure what you are wanting to do exactly.

Comment: I can't reproduce this in Xcode 10 (Swift 4.2). You code seems to work fine. It is possible this is already fixed.

Comment: @Augie What I want to do is what's described : make services generic and conforming to a protocol, for which the associated type is another protocol. I guess it's something that cannot be expressed in swift

Comment: @RobNapier I cannot make it compile either with Xcode 10 / swift 4.2 :/

Comment: Ah, yes, I've reproduced it now. A protocol that inherits from a protocol does not conform to that protocol (just as a protocol does not conform to itself). The answer is to reduce your use of protocols. If you already have two classes (A and B), make them subclasses of a single abstract class. Or create a type-eraser. http://robnapier.net/erasure But you're pushing protocols beyond what they can do. Protocols with associated types are extremely tricky in Swift and should not be used unless you absolutely require them. They have many limitations.

Comment: Given this specific case, though, I'd be looking hard at just holding generic closures rather than using protocols at all. Take a look at this for discussion on that: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QCxkaTj7QJs

Answer (score 0):

Not positive I follow your desired outcome, but try this

```
struct delegateList<T> {

var items: [T]

mutating func add(item: T){
    items.append(item)
    }
}



protocol Delegable {

    var delegates: delegateList<someProtocol>
    func register(delegate: someProtocol)

}
```

Comment: Got the same issue. I have to add associatedType D: Delegate into your Delegable protocol. Then when implementing the service, I have to try something like typealias D = <someprotocol conforming to Delegate> but the compiler still does not like it.